# What are those threads I see on a new python console?

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7

I'm just starting to learn about threads and I came up to this. Within a fresh new console I type:

```
import threading
print threading.enumerate()
```

and I get this:

```
[<Thread(Thread-3, started daemon 14768)>, <Thread(Thread-2, started daemon 11364)>, <_MainThread(MainThread, started 7472)>]
```

What are those Thread-2 and Thread-3? is it normal? is there a way to kill them?

As far as I understood, only the MainThread should appear no?

Comment: What "console" environment are you running this in?

Comment: @Carcigenicate The one I get in PyCharm

Comment: I'm going to guess they're spawned by Pycharm to do things like update the watched variables or something. They'd likely just be helper threads to handle some things in the background.

Comment: @Carcigenicate ah ok thanks